# Vim:E523: Not allowed here

Tags: python, vim-plugin

I received this error when i tab in vim.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "< string >", line 1, in < module >
>   File "utils.py", line 15, in write
>   current_buffer.append('some text')
>   vim.error: Vim:E523: Not allowed here

I have the current .vim file

```
if expand("%:e") == 'xml'                                                                                                                                                             
    inoremap <expr> <tab> WriteFile()                                                                                                                                                 
endif                                                                                                                                                                                 
function! WriteFile()                                                                                                                                                                 
    python3 utils.write()                                                                                                                                                             
endfunction
```

and this .py file

```py
import vim

def write():
    current_buffer = vim.current.buffer
    current_buffer.append('some text')
```

Comment: I was wondering if you know the error "INSTROPESCTABLE METADATA NOT FOUND" ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue is happening because you're not allowed to modify the current buffer while evaluating an expression for a mapping.

See [`:help :map-expression`](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#%3Amap-expression), more specifically:

> Be very careful about side effects!  The expression is evaluated while
>   obtaining characters, you may very well make the command dysfunctional.
>   For this reason the following is blocked:
>
> - Changing the buffer text ([textlock](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#textlock)).
> - Editing another buffer.
> - The `:normal` command.
> - Moving the cursor is allowed, but it is restored afterwards.
>
> If you want the mapping to do any of these let the returned characters do
>   that.

You should either have the function *return* the characters to be inserted, or consider using a non-`<expr>` mapping, with an explicit `:call`.

For the former, returning the characters to be inserted:

```
inoremap <expr> <tab> WriteFile()
function! WriteFile()
    return py3eval('utils.write()')
endfunction
```

And the `utils.py` file:

```
def write():
    return 'some text'
```

Or, the alternative approach of using a non-`<expr>` mapping:

```
inoremap <tab> <C-O>:call WriteFile()<CR>
```

(The latter might have some unwanted side-effects, as you'll return to insert mode after modifying the buffer, but you'll return to the same position you were before the mapping. You might want to consider using `setpos()` or similar to move the cursor after the mapping, if needed.)